# Recursive call on table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
declare @departments table
(
depa_key int,
depa_key1 int
)

insert into @departments(depa_key, depa_key1)
select 1,2
union all
select 2,4
union all
select 4,5
```

So, after filling some data, table looks like this:

```
depa_key    depa_key1
1               2
2               4
4               5
5              NULL
```

DEPA_KEY1 is always a parent from `DEPA_KEY.

What I would like to do is get whole hierachy (all depa_key1) for given `depa_key`.

Example:
For depa_key = 1 result should be:

```
depa_key
2
4
5
```

But I don't know how to do this?

Comment: This is a typical recursive cte. There are hundreds of questions covering this on SO and thousands around the internet. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Is there any other way than using CTE?

Comment: What is wrong with using a rCTE for this? You could use loops but it is highly inefficient, requires a LOT more code, is more prone to error, is far more difficult to maintain...and did I mention slower?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
;with cte as (
    select depa_key1 from @departments where depa_key = 1
    union all
    select d.depa_key1 from cte c join @departments d on c.depa_key1 = d.depa_key
)
select * from cte;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/MWUU89233)

Comment: Is it possible to solve this same problem without CTE?

Comment: @FrenkyB - Yes and No. Yes if the number of levels are fixed and known in advance. No if it's variable. Another way would be using procedural approach - which might not perform as well as you'd like